# Web Application Server Home Directory

Tags: websphere, rational-rsa

This is a very basic question for which I've spent unnecessarily hours. What is the home directory of the  Web Application Server 6 (WAS6) when installed through Rational Software Architect.

I am using WAS6 with RSA for development and need to set the WAS6_HOME environment variable. I am not sure as to what path should be set to this environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if WAS 6.1 was installed it should be RSA_INSTALL_HOME/runtimes/base_v61. I have it as c:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtime\base_v61

Comment: Thanks mate that gave my answer for me it is:
C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP75_RSA\runtimes\base_v6